# installing libvirt in a virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, openstack, kvm, libvirt, openstack-nova

I want to install a basic architecture of OpenSatck using VirtualBox (3 VM nodes: *controller*, *network* and *compute*).
I wanted to install libvirt within the *compute* VM but the KVM virtualization is not supported inside the VM as this command does not return any result

```sh
$ egrep '^flags.*(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

I ignore this and install libvirt but when I check if it's OK using this command:

```sh
$ lsmod | grep kvm
```

unfortunately nothing appears.

I don't know how can I proceed and then install the *compute* node on a virtual machine.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, KVM virtualization is not supported inside your VM, so you would not expect to see the `kvm` module loaded.  Libvirt should work fine using software emulation.

If you have libvirt installed and running, you can use the `virsh capabilities` command to verify the functionality of your environment.  You would expect the output to include at least `<guest>` entries for `i686` and `x86_64`:

```
# virsh capabilities
[...]
  <guest>
    <os_type>hvm</os_type>
    <arch name='i686'>
[...]
  </guest>

  <guest>
    <os_type>hvm</os_type>
    <arch name='x86_64'>
[...]
  </guest>
```

Comment: it has shown me a <host> entry of x86_64 and the two <guest> entries for i686 and x86_64. so i can say everything is ok .